# Headless UI Automation Testing using UFT

Tags: automation, hp-uft, ui-testing, headless-browser

Is there a way to run our automation scripts in UFT using Headless browsers, similar to what we do using selenium?

The scripts that i am running now consumes up lot of time and are very slow.

I am relatively new to UFT and did some research on the web w.r.t headless testing using UFT but couldn't find any.

Any pointers or suggestions shall be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking similar to below code?

```
Public Function GetAllLinksInthePage()
    Dim oIE
    Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    oIE.Visible = False
    oIE.Navigate2 "http://newtours.demoaut.com/"
    Wait 4
    Set oIEDocument = oIE.Document
    Set oLinkCollection = oIEDocument.getElementsByTagName("A")
    iLinkCount = oLinkCollection.Length
    If iLinkCount > 0 Then
        For iCount = 0 To iLinkCount - 1
            Print oLinkCollection(iCount).Text
        Next
    End If  
    Set oIE = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you application offers rich set of API in form REST or SOA, you can use XMLHTTP object. It is independent of QTP/UFT. It's pure VBSscript and can be used anywhere. The sad part is that you must do lot of coding from scratch, but it is quite easy.

```html
dim xmlhttp, fso, f1, serverURL
Set xmlhttp = Createobject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
serverURL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=Atlanta+GA+USA&destinations=Dallas+TX+USA&units=imperial&sensor=false"
xmlhttp.Open "POST", serverURL, false
xmlhttp.Send
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f1 = fso.CreateTextFile("D:\Sample VB Scripts\testfile.xml", True)
f1.write xmlhttp.ResponseText
f1.close
```

[Sample XMLHTTP code](https://helloacm.com/using-xmlhttp-in-vbscript/)